# Unable to click on the CheckBox in AutoIt

Tags: autoit

The below one is my program. Here my intention is to display the three *CheckBoxes* after the user presses the *Button*. They do appear after clicking the `ok`-*Button*, but I'm unable to click on the *CheckBoxes*. What could be the reason?

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>  
$gui = GuiCreate("Hello World", 700, 600) 
$Label_HelloWorld = GuiCtrlCreateLabel("Path", 40, 20, 300, 600)
$Button_OK = GuiCtrlCreateButton("OK", 450, 20, 50, 20)    

GuiSetState(@SW_SHOW, $gui) 
While True
    $guimsg = GuiGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $guimsg == $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            GuiDelete($gui)
            ExitLoop

        Case $guimsg == $Button_OK
            $Label_sub_folder1 = GuiCtrlCreateLabel("Select the subfolder", 40, 65, 300, 600) 
            $CheckBox1 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('functionality', 40, 85, 80, 23)
            $CheckBox2 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('performance', 160, 85, 80, 23)
            $CheckBox3 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox('listening', 280, 85, 80, 23)
            Sleep(50000)
            ExitLoop

    EndSelect
WEnd
```

Comment: Is this typical in AutoIT, that you use `while 1` never ending loop like this?

Comment: @Kamil, Sorry for that, I've edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the label is a lot larger than it needs to be (600px tall), and is covering up the checkboxes. To fix just change the height to a more reasonable value (I usually use 18px for single line labels).

As an extra note, you shouldn't sleep inside a message loop. The messages will just queue up and the GUI will not be responsive. Instead you should have a timer that can run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Your code style is a mess... Let's look at this code:

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>

$gui = GUICreate("Test")
$button = GUICtrlCreateButton("ok", 200, 10, 40, 23)
$checkbox = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("checkbox1", 10, 10, 80, 23)
GUICtrlSetState($checkbox, $GUI_HIDE)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While True
   Switch GUIGetMsg()
      Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
         ExitLoop
      Case $button
         GUICtrlSetState($checkbox, $GUI_SHOW)
   EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Where's the difference? Its label size isn't way too big in height. And it's defining every needed control element before showing the GUI. And just the elements you want to be shown later are first hidden and then shown...

So your main problem is your label height in both statements, which will create a label that covers all of your following GUI elements making them unusable. You can - if you need to - use `GUICtrlSetState($background, $GUI_DISABLE)` with some kind of `$background`-component like a label or a graphics to prevent it from staying at top and hindering other GUI elements to work properly.