# unable to enter data in Input Control of a GUI in autoit

Tags: user-interface, user-input, autoit

The below one is my code. I am unable to click and edit in the second Input control.

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3> 

$gui = GuiCreate("Hello World", 700, 600) 
$Label_HelloWorld = GuiCtrlCreateLabel("Path / Directory", 40, 20, 300, 18) 
$file = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 140, 20, 300, 20)

$Label_boot = GuiCtrlCreateLabel("path of boot.c", 40, 60, 300, 18) 
$file2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 140, 60, 300, 20)
$Button_OK = GuiCtrlCreateButton("CHECK", 400, 90, 50, 20)

GuiSetState(@SW_SHOW, $gui)
Sleep(10000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your labels are overlapping the controls ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403853/unable-to-click-on-the-checkbox-in-autoit)), this time horizontally. A width of 300px when the inputs are 100px to the right means the first 200px is overlapping. If you try to click in the last 100px of the input then it will work.

This is very easy to check for, just use the autoit window info tool and look at the outlines of the controls.

Comment: Just a site note: If you are working with constant strings it is not necessary to give width and height for labels.  `GuiCtrlCreateLabel("Path / Directory", 40, 20)` creates a label that is wide and high enough to display the given text.